# DDMS screenshot not in sync with vsync

Tags: android, ddms

I'm currently developing a game for Android and I want to take screenshots of it.
I did so using the DDMS tool in eclipse. However, most of the screenshots are a mix of two frames:

```
___________
|new frame|
|         |
|         |
|_________|
|old frame|
|         |
|_________|
```

The separating line is in different positions.

This leads me to the conclusion that the screenshot is being made while the current frame is still being drawn.

Is there a way to get the screencap in sync with the hardware?

Are there other methods of making screenshots where this doesn't happen?

Thanks in advance for any hints!

Update: See my last comment on accepted answer for my solution.

Comment: Take a look at system/core/adb/framebuffer_service.c.  It's just opening /dev/graphics/fb0, using an ioctl to get the parameters, and then copying the whole thing out 256 bytes at a time with multiple read/write calls.

Comment: thx but I don't want to go at that level for just taking screenshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this might be a crappy solution, but it would be a quick one.  Can you (temporarily, debug only, etc.) have the game paused such that you can take the screenshots?  Aka, "freeze" a single frame of time?

Comment: yeah I tried that, but I wasn't able to stop the game before the screen was cleared again. I will try this again should no more convenient solution be found. thx

Comment: Can you run it under debug and set a breakpoint to the right spot in code (before/after redraw)?

Comment: totally forgot about using breakpoints - it's so obvious! I will try that after Hrk's suggestion, thx

Comment: I tried it and found something easier: the thread "suspend" button. Don't need to think about where to place breakpoints, I can simply pause the game this way, make a screenshot and continue. Thanks for leading me there!

Answer (score 0):

Complicate way:
Have a look at vnc-server app. If your device is rooted, it can display camera video flow without the problem you explain. But it uses a lot of jni file and could be complicated to integrate only to take some screenshot. Or you can root your device, install the application and take snapshot on your computer vnc-client application.

https://github.com/oNaiPs/droid-VNC-server/tree/

Application on market : "org.onaips.vnc"

Comment: That sounds like a great solution! My device is rooted, let's see.

Comment: Ok I tried it and the vnc works, but it is really laggy even over lan and it does have the same problem: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/456585/so_vnc.png

Comment: Perhaps have a look at this:http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9bb67dcf79d95cdd

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but the thread suspend button is much more convenient, see above answer. The vnc might come in handy in other situations though!